# Unusual error while installing any pip based package

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel

I do not remember since when, but whenever I install any `pip` based package, my system (Ubuntu 14.04, Python 2.7.6) trows a warning/error :

```
Url 'file:///home/username/.pip-wheelhouse' is ignored: it is neither a file nor a directory.
```

I don't know where this line came from but the pip package I'm installing installs very well, but this line is always shown. How can I remove this ?

Comment: see this: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Wheelhouse  try pip with --no-cache-dir parameter.

Comment: Nope. not working at all. I think there must be somewhere  that line is written so that whenever I install a package, it reads there.

Comment: if you want to disappear this warning you can remove it from index.py
around line 216
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things that can cause this. First take a look at your [pip configuration file](https://pip-cn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuration.html#config-file) at `~/.pip/pip.conf` and see if it contains a section like this:

```
[wheel]
wheel-dir = /home/username/.pip-wheelhouse
```

If so, comment that section out, use pip, and see if that gets rid of the message.

This config file specifies the same information as some environment variables. Try this:

```
env | grep -i wheel
```

This command will list all of your environment variables that contain the word `wheel`. If you see any output, look for a line that specifies the `.pip-wheelhouse` directory. For example, `PIP_FIND_LINKS` [is the top suspect](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#environment-variables). When you've found the culprit and you just need to track down where those variables are getting set. The top candidate files for setting variables like that would be `~/.bashrc`, `~/.profile`, and `/etc/profile`. Search those files for the word `wheel` and I suspect you'll be able to resolve this.

Comment: found that in `~/.pip/pip.conf` and commented it out. thanks.